# Fill a mat-table with json from GET response

Tags: angular, get, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I am sending a query to the back-end and I want to fill a table with the information from the response. I am connecting services trough HTTP request GET.

app.component.ts:

```
results: any;
displayedColumns: string[] = ['bank', 'exchange', 'fee', 'cost'];
isLoading = true;

submitForm(amountMoney: string, amountTransactions: string) {
    this.service.getCalculations(this.selectedCountryFrom, this.selectedCountryTo,
      this.selectedCurrencyFrom, this.selectedCurrencyTo,
      amountMoney, amountTransactions).subscribe((response) => {
        this.results = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.results.data = response['body'];
        console.log(response);
        console.log(this.results);
        console.log(this.results.data);
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <h1>List of the banks</h1>

  <table mat-table [dataSource]="results">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="bank">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Bank</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let bank"> {{bank.bank}} </td>
    </ng-container>
...

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

I can see I am getting a json response when inspecting in the browser, however i cannot fill the mat-table with data. I only see the headers of the columns when i get a response, but nothing inside.

How can I get that json and fill the mat-table?

Answer (score 0):

After getting data from API, you are setting response to `this.results.data`. Instead do like this:

```
this.results = new MatTableDataSource(response['body']);
```

Reference : https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples